# can't import pubsub for python SDK appengine / psutil

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

As I work on pubsub and Google App Engine, I'm running into some issues with psutil when I try to import pubsub_v1.
Pubsub is doing nice work when I run it separately but when I use dev_appserver for app engine, I got this traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/soussa77/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/soussa77/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/soussa77/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/Users/soussa77/PycharmProjects/my-project/apps/app1/src/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from src.apis.app1 import App1Api
  File "/Users/soussa77/PycharmProjects/my-project/apps/app1/src/apis/app1.py", line 11, in <module>
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
  File "/Users/soussa77/PycharmProjects/my-project/apps/app1/lib/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import types
  File "/Users/soussa77/PycharmProjects/my-project/app/waterp/lib/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/types.py", line 17, in <module>
    import psutil
  File "/Users/soussa77/PycharmProjects/my-project/apps/app1/lib/psutil/__init__.py", line 156, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Users/soussa77/PycharmProjects/my-project/apps/app1/lib/psutil/_psosx.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx as cext
  File "/Users/soussa77/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1091, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
**ImportError: No module named psutil._psutil_osx**
```

It looks like it fails at psutil when pubsub try to monitor cpu activity.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using App Engine standard or flex? I am assuming you are using standard based on the log.

The short answer is that Google App Engine Standard does not seems to fully support the google cloud client lib really well at the moment. Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3892. There is a work around in this thread by mocking the `psutil` but I have not tried it myself.

Inside this issue, it points you this issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1893 which is tracking the status. It is still open at this moment.